# Howto set limit result per page in jpa and PagingAndSortingRepository?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Have a Spring Boot Blog project, and need show the lastest favorites post in main page, in the database have a table with the posts and a column with boolean value (tinyint) show_in_main_page, it define if the post show in the main page or not.

In the java controller get dinamicaly widgets and the get the lastest favorites post by each widget, have a foreach with each widget but need get 1 or more post by each widget, i using PagingAndSortingRepository and Page<> results, in the while of controller call nextPageable() and next last favorite post.

Howto set the 1 result for each page in the repository? howto make a dinamicaly function with the number of results per page?, by example: call repository to get 3 results by page called from the controller when 3 is a dinamicaly value.

My interface is:

```
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PostEntity, Long>{
    Page<PostEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<PostEntity> findByShowInMainPage(Boolean showInMainPage); // <--
}
```

Comment: When you say you are trying to do this from the controller, are you using the built in spring functionality to pass the query parameters? /mypage?page=1&size=3

Comment: need internal use, no manipulable use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need `PageRequest`:

```
Page<PostEntity> postEntityPage = findAll(new PageRequest(0, 3));
```

It fetch first (0) page with three `PostEntity` in the page.

Comment: simulate a `LIMIT 0, 3` but if call the next page return the next 3 results? need unlimited results but only x results per pagination, by example 3 per each page in results.

Comment: @e-info128 the first parameter of `PageRequest` is the number of the page - 0, 1, 2...

Comment: Thanks works for me, i use `new PageRequest(0, items_per_page, Sort.Direction.DESC, "created_at")` when items_per_page is 1 and by each widget of posts call `postEntity = posts.getContent().get(item_id); posts.nextPageable(); item_id++;`. Now have a last favorite post by each widget dinamicaly without obtain all posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get paging from the controller, just add a parameter on the control for Pageable.  For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String entries(@PathVariable(PATH_USERNAME) final String username,
                          final Pageable pageable,
                          final Model model) {
...
```

This will give you parameters automatically on your controller for page and size. So the URL would look like /users/myusername?page=1&size=3 and would return the first 3 results. Setting page = 2 would get you the next 3 results and so on.

You can then pass the pageable variable to your repository's findAll method to get the data.

Comment: Thanks but not need pass the controll of values by request parameters, need dinamicaly show a specific number of values determinated by administrator or develop only.